# No CSS styles seen in email

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, mutt

I am unable to see CSS styles when the following html page is emailed(Yahoo/Gmail) using mutt.I just see a plain table.But I get desired styling when viewed it in a browser. Why is that so ? Am I missing something ?

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" me@mail.com -s "Test" < Test.html
```

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
rd{ color: red; }
gn{ color: green; }
body { background-color:#E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica;font-size: 15px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" align ="left">
<tr><th>No.</th><th>Item</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td><gn>abc</gn></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><rd>ghi</rd></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `rd` and `gn`?

Comment: Try adding the style inline - most email clients strip out style tags.

Comment: You have invalid HTML, You need to close your last `<tr>` and `gn` is not an HTML tag.

Comment: Use span or font tags instead of `<gn>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html-email is very limited to the point where even div and p tags don't always act as expected. Trying to create your own tags is simply asking for trouble.

Your two table cells should look like this instead:

```
<tr><td>1</td><td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color:#007700;">abc</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color:#770000;">ghi</td></tr>
```

In addition to always inlining your CSS, you need to use the 6-digit hex color for maximum email client support. You must also re-declare your font styles in every table cell. Redundant as it is, unfortunately that is what is needed in html-email.

Don't forget the font stack also, as you are currently assuming the reader has Helvetica installed.

Comment: Hmm..This is a lot of redundant code for a table with several columns and rows. I guess I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 4):

The way to include CSS in an HTML email is to use inline styles.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body style='background-color:#E0E0E0; font-family: helvetica;font-size: 15px;'>
        <table border="1" align="left" style="color:red;">
            <tr><th>No.</th><th>Item</th></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td><gn>abc</gn></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ref: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3679231

Comment: @Jean But you get the concept, use inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have a look at this tutorial [Getting Started with HTML Emails](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/getting-started-with-html-emails/) on [tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/) this is an old tutorial but really helpful one.

best of luck.